# Can I design this database better?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql

I have  the following database design:

[image]

Script to reproduce:

```
  /*
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[feedback]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[action]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[download]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[user]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[company]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[resource]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[task]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[subcategory]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[category]
  */  

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user]
    (
      [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                     NOT NULL ,
      [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [DepartmentID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [EmailAddress] [varchar](150) NOT NULL ,
      [Title] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [FirstName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL ,
      [MiddleName] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [LastName] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [DateOfBirth] [date] NULL ,
      [ResidentialAddress] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [ResidentialSuburb] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialPostCode] [varchar](20) NULL ,
      [ResidentialState] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialCountry] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [PostalAddress] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [PostalSuburb] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [PostalPostCode] [varchar](20) NULL ,
      [PostalState] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [PostalCountry] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [Phone] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [Mobile] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [BrowserDetails] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL ,
      [LastLogin] [datetime] NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [UserId] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[company]
    (
      [CompanyID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                        NOT NULL ,
      [CompanyName] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [DepartmentID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [DepartmentName] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialAddress] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [ResidentialSuburb] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialPostCode] [varchar](20) NULL ,
      [ResidentialState] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialCountry] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [PostalAddress] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [PostalSuburb] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [PostalPostCode] [varchar](20) NULL ,
      [PostalState] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [PostalCountry] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [Phone] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_department] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [DepartmentID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [company]
ADD CONSTRAINT CompanyID_DepartmentID_UQ
UNIQUE (CompanyID, DepartmentID);
GO

ALTER TABLE [user]
ADD CONSTRAINT Company_User_FK
FOREIGN KEY (CompanyID, DepartmentID) 
REFERENCES company (CompanyID, DepartmentID);
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[resource]
    (
      [ResourceID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                         NOT NULL ,
      [ResourceName] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL ,
      [ResourceUrl] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL ,
      [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_resource] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ResourceID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[download]
    (
      [DownloadID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                         NOT NULL ,
      [ResourceID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [UserID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [DownloadDate] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [ActionID] [int] NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_download] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [DownloadID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[download]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_download_resource] FOREIGN KEY([ResourceID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[resource] ([ResourceID])

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[download]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_download_userid] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[user] ([UserID])

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[category]
    (
      [CategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                         NOT NULL ,
      [CategoryTitle] [varchar](200) NOT NULL ,
      [WordpressPostID] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [CategoryID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[subcategory]
    (
      [SubCategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                            NOT NULL ,
      [SubCategoryTitle] [varchar](200) NOT NULL ,
      [CategoryID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [WordpressPostID] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_subcategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        ( [SubCategoryID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[subcategory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_subcategory_categoryid] FOREIGN KEY([CategoryID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[category] ([CategoryID])

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[task]
    (
      [TaskID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                     NOT NULL ,
      [TaskTitle] [varchar](200) NOT NULL ,
      [SubCategoryID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_task] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [TaskID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_task_SubCategoryID] FOREIGN KEY([SubCategoryID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[subcategory] ([SubCategoryID])

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[action]
    (
      [ActionID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                       NOT NULL ,
      [ActionTitle] [varchar](250) NULL ,
      [TaskID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [UserID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [StartDate] [date] NULL ,
      [EndDate] [date] NULL ,
      [OnGoing] [bit] NULL ,
      [Completed] [bit] NULL ,
      [CompletedDate] [datetime] NULL ,
      [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_action] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ActionID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[action]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_action_TaskID] FOREIGN KEY([TaskID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[task] ([TaskID])

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[action]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_action_UserID] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[user] ([UserID])

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[feedback]
    (
      [FeedbackID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [FeedbackDate] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      [ActionID] [int] NULL ,
      [CategoryID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [UserID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [Feedback] [varchar](MAX) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_feedback] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [FeedbackID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[feedback]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_feedback_UserID] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[user] ([UserID])

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[feedback]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_feedback_CategoryID] FOREIGN KEY([CategoryID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[category] ([CategoryID])

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

GO
```

**Database Intent**
The intent of the database is that a user will complete quizzes (actions) in various sub-categories and have the ability to provide feedback on each action (as well as track the resources the user downloads as they proceed).

**Usage Information**
It's expected that there is an average of 43 actions per subcategory and there will be five subcategories total (to begin with). Our user base is ~30,000 users of which we expect only 5,000 or so to actually use this system.

Is  there a better approach to this design? What holes do I have in my design that I should look to resolving?

Comment: Since there are so many possibilities for this, unfortunately I have to vote to close this question.  If you have a specific design problem, edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: The question is too broad. You need to bake down to a simple problem that can be engaged here on stackexchange. Should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Category and Subcategory should be one table, and you should have a parent_id foreign key pointing to its own primary key. If it's not null, then it's a subcategory.

A User is a User and not a Person. You should also abstract Company and Person into one type (Party), so you are not repeating details. A User belongs to a Party (or has a has-one relationship). Read up on Table Inheritance.

You should also break out Address into its own type. A Party can have zero or more addresses, and multiple Parties can reside at the same Address. So you need a junction table between Party and Address.

A Task (which is really a Question?) can only belong to a Subcategory? You probably want a junction table between Task and Category.

A User can only provide Feedback on a Category? Why don't they provide feedback on the Question?

What is a resource? A file that someone downloads? Calling it File would be clearer.